# UICollectionView does not respond to drag/swipe in Catalyst

Tags: mac-catalyst

In a Catalyst app, I have SceneWindow in which is placed a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.   I can use opt-left and opt-right arrow to get it to scroll left/right, but it will not respond to the mouse swipe.

Adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to a cell gets handled properly.

Various "enables" of Scrolling, UserInteraction, Paging for the collection view have no effect.